# Escaping ' (apostrophe) in \\' (leader leader apostrophe) in a @let statement inside .vimrc

Tags: macro, escape

I have mapping  `\\'` (leader leader apostrophe) within my .vimrc.
The mapping works just fine.

I have recorded a macro to key `e` using this mapping.
`qe ... steps ... q`
The macro works just fine.

then I dumped the macro to text with
`"ep`
The macro text is `\\'0<80>kd`

I have placed this handy macro in my `.vimrc` as
`let @e ='\\'0<80>kd'`

The problem is I can't work out how to escape the apsotrophe that appears just before the 0.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two single quotes to do this:

```
let @e = '\\''0<80>kd'
```

See [`:help literal-string`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#literal-string):

> This string is taken as it is.  No backslashes are removed or have a special meaning.  **The only exception is that two quotes stand for one quote.**

*(Emphasis mine)*

You could also have done this by using a regular [double quoted string](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-string). The disadvantage is that you have to escape your backslashes. The big advantage however, is that you can then use [Vim's escapes](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) instead of literal control characters, which makes your config more readable *and* more copy/pasteable:

```
let @e = "\\\\'0\<down>"
```

Or if you prefer:

```
let @e = '\\' . "'0\<down>"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was scratching my head and had tried the usual variations of swapping single surrounding quotes for surrounding double quotes etc.

Comment: @Kes I updated my answer with some more info about how and why you might want to do this with double quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Rich, great answer, appreciated :)

Comment: @Kes Glad I could help!